# Return a value / cancel installation with vbscript custom action

Tags: vbscript, wix, installation, custom-action, wix3.7

I have a custom action in my installer that opens a message box using a vbscript custom action.

```
<CustomAction Id="EXENotFound" Script="vbscript" Return="check">
      <![CDATA[
        Dim i
        If session.Property("REMINDEX_SHORTCUT") = "" Then
          i = MsgBox(session.Property("TextProp"), 1)
        End If
      ]]>
</CustomAction>
```

I want to cancel the installation if the value of i = 2 (if cancel is pressed in the message box). I think I can get the installation to cancel if my script returns a value of 3, but it only ever returns 0. I've tried this:

```
Dim i
If session.Property("REMINDEX_SHORTCUT") = "" Then
  i = MsgBox(session.Property("TextProp"), 1)
End If
If i = 2 Then
  return 3
End If
```

which throws some error about 'type mismatch'.

I also tried this when I got desperate:

```
<CustomAction Id="EXENotFound" Script="vbscript" Return="check">
          <![CDATA[
            Dim i
            If session.Property("REMINDEX_SHORTCUT") = "" Then
              i = MsgBox(session.Property("TextProp"), 1)
            End If
            If i = 2 Then
              EXENotFound = 3
            End If
          ]]> 
</CustomAction>
```

I've done extensive research online but have not been able to find how to cancel the installation from a custom action or even how to simply return 3 manually.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should be using the Windows Installer UI not a custom action. Start [here](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/interactions).

Comment: Thanks! That works much better. However, now that I have that message popping up when "Install" is clicked, I've lost the actual install functionality. Do you know the event that should be fired to start the installation so I can link that to one of the controls in my custom prompt instead of the default install button? I tried to find the event in the VerifyReadyDlg source code but could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

I only dabbled with WiX a little, and it's been some years since then, but I think you need to put your code in a function:

```
<CustomAction Id="EXENotFound" Script="vbscript" Return="check">
  <![CDATA[
    Function AskUser
      AskUser = 0
      If session.Property("REMINDEX_SHORTCUT") = "" Then
        AskUser = MsgBox(session.Property("TextProp"), 1)
      End If
    End Function
  ]]>
</CustomAction>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the UI sequence, then the correct way to do this is to show a standard dialog built using your MSI development tool, and wire up the Cancel logic if that's one of the choices. That's mostly covered by other answers. The correct way to show a message in the execute sequence (from a custom action) is to call MsiProcessMessage (or installer object or DTF managed CA equivalents). Return IDCANCEL if appropriate.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370354(v=vs.85).aspx

http://microsoft.public.platformsdk.msi.narkive.com/oKHfPSZc/using-msiprocessmessage-in-a-c-custom-action